# Git のフックスクリプトで、単なる commit か merge commit かを区別出来るのか？

Tags: git

実現したいことは、あるブランチで直接 `commit` することを禁止し、他のブランチからの `merge commit` のみを許すことです。例えば、 Gitflow で運用した時に `develop` ブランチへの直接 `commit` を禁止して、 `feature` や `release` ブランチなどからの `merge commit` だけを認めることを開発メンバに強要したいといったケースです。

コミット前にチェックするための仕掛けとして `pre-commit` フックを使うのが最も自然だと思うんですが、実行されたのが `commit` か `merge --no-ff` による `merge commit` かをフックスクリプト(hook scripts)の中で区別する手段ってあるんでしょうか？

もしくは `pre-commit` フックを使わずに上記を実現する方法はあるんでしょうか？

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`pre-commit` フックを使用しない方法はちょっと分からないので，素直に `pre-commit` フックを使用した方法を示します．

`develop` ブランチへの `commit` を禁止するには， `.git/hooks/pre-commit` を

```
#!/bin/sh    
# Redirect output to stderr.
exec 1>&2

if [ "`git symbolic-ref HEAD | sed -e 's@^refs/heads/@@'`" = develop ]
then
    echo "cannot commit on develop branch."
    exit 1
fi
```

などとするとできます．

`git symbolic-ref HEAD` により `HEAD` が何であるか調べ， `develop` であれば `exit 1`で終了するという流れです．

参考ページにも詳しく書いてあるのですが，

- `commit` の処理順序

  1. `git commit` コマンドの実行
  2. `pre-commit` フックの実行
  3. デフォルトメッセージ生成
  4. `prepare-commit-msg` フックの実行
  5. コミットメッセージエディターが起動
  6. `commit-msg` フックの実行
  7. 実際にコミット生成
  8. `post-commit` フックの実行
- `merge` の処理順序

  1. `git merge` コマンドの実行
  2. `prepare-commit-msg` フックの実行
  3. 実際にマージの実行
  4. `post-merge` フックの実行

となっています．そのため， `pre-commit` フックを使用すれば `git merge` はそのまま実行でき， `git commit` だけを実行禁止するか否かの判断ができます．

ちなみに， `git commit --no-verify` でフックは回避できてしまうので注意してください．

参考：

- [Gitのフックの説明と挙動の検証](http://qiita.com/mima_ita/items/dcaa3789022d2a9ab929)
- [Git hooks まとめ](http://qiita.com/khlizard/items/dfe1ec9d82c0ed5da7c6)
- [Git-のカスタマイズ-Git-フック](http://git-scm.com/book/ja/v1/Git-%E3%81%AE%E3%82%AB%E3%82%B9%E3%82%BF%E3%83%9E%E3%82%A4%E3%82%BA-Git-%E3%83%95%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF)